# Linq to entities (mysql) produces sql error

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have an issue with Linq to entities (with mysql provider) throwing a runtime exception.

I have a results table. I want to produce a list of results, sorted by and grouped by `ResultDate` but only returning me the rows for the top three values (for each date). I have written this as linq:

```
var query = from res in results
            group res by res.resultDate into g
            orderby g.Key
            select new 
            {
                ResultDate = g.Key,
                ResultList = g.ToList()
                              .OrderByDescending(r => r.Value)
                              .Take(3)
            };
```

When I include the `.Take(3)`, the query fails with an exception (thrown from MySql.Data.dll) with the message "Subquery returns more than 1 row".

However, if I simply query the results table and pull back all rows into a list, and then run the exact same linq against the list, it runs just fine.

Is the linq badly formed, hence the sql being emmitted is not correct, or could this be a bug in the mysql linq provider?

Comment: Does removing `ToList()` help?

Comment: Thanks, no it doesn't make any difference (but yes it is redundant)

Comment: Have you tried to put this on LinqPAD and see the SQL it generates?

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure how that is going to help me?  I can see the underlying SQL in the VS debugger, but that hasn't really helped me understand why it works as linq to objects but not linq to entities.